# Firebase keeps reverting firestore rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I had a rule for accessing firestore that limited it to before 2/20 for development purposes. Since that date passed, I updated the rule. But every few days I get an error saying the client didn't have permission to access firestore. I go into the console, and it says I updated the rules five minutes ago that reverted the access rules back to the 2/20 date.

I'm not changing anything, but it seems to be automatically reverting. What is causing this?[image]

Comment: Could it be that you're automatically deploying these rules when you run `firebase deploy`?

Comment: i think that might be it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you're automatically deploying these rules when you run `firebase deploy`?

If so, make sure that either your local rules files is up to date, or that you [run `firebase deploy` with the `--only` flag](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets#deploy-target-commands) and indicate precisely what it needs to deploy.